# How to access an array with TAL

Tags: python, plone, zope, tal

I have a python file which creates an array with a path to an image and a page URL

```
self.banner1 = [self.context.defaultBanner1.filename,self.context.defaultBanner1bUrl]
```

I want to access this within my page using TAL. I have tried this without success

```
<h1 tal:content="view/banner1[0]"></h1>
```

How do I access the array using TAL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with a path expression, but you can use a Python expression:

```
<h1 tal:content="python:view.banner1[0]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a view that make it for you (and test if the array is not empty).

```
def get_banner(self, banner):
    """ """
    if banner:
        return banner[0]
```

In the template :

```
<h1 tal:content="view/get_banner"></h1>
```